# MySQL Performance - Large Table Random Row with Where Clause

Tags: mysql, performance, random, where-clause

I have a MySQL table storing about 330,000 records at the moment.  I need to write a quick and efficient query to pull 15 random records, but with a where clause based off flags.

For example, a couple options I've tried (with bad efficiency I might add) :

**SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl WHERE flag IN ('opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15;**

This query takes about 3 seconds, which is too slow.  Another option I was working with was taking the number of desired rows returned (15 in this case) and dividing by the total # of rows with flags requested (which equals $x), and then running this query :

**SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl WHERE RAND()<= '$x' AND flag IN ('opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3');**

This usually returns 14-16 rows, so that's not a big deal.  I don't need it to return exactly 15, but close.  This option shaved a second off the query time, however it's still too high for production use.

I should note all of the records have an assigned ID #, starting at 1.  No holes.

Maybe I'm just over-thinking this.  Does anyone have any good alternatives they've used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating the 15 integer IDs in memory before calling the query... to which you've added a nice `IN` clause.  You'll have to get the maximal ID first, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to not have to put them all into memory, but it appears that's what we have to do.

Comment: How about this: [jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)